# Attach generated CSV file to email and send with Django

Tags: python, django

I need to generate a csv file based on the queryset result, attach the resulting file to an email as attachment and send. As you can see i need to iterate over the assigned_leads and write it to a file so i thought yield would do the trick. Now when i run the code i receive the email with attachment with below message instead of the rows i expect. If i use return i get the one row from the queryset result.

```
<generator object data at 0x7f5e508d93c0>

def send_lead_reminder(request):
    usercompany = Listing.objects.filter(submitted_by=request.user)
    assigned_leads = lead.objects.filter(assigned_to__in=usercompany).distinct() 
    def data():
        csvfile=StringIO.StringIO()
        csvwriter =csv.writer(csvfile)
        for leads in assigned_leads:
            csvwriter.writerow([leads.business_name, leads.first_name, leads.last_name, leads.email, leads.phone_number,leads.address, leads.city, leads.state, leads.zipcode, leads.submission_date, leads.time_frame, leads.comments])
             yield csvfile.getvalue()
    message = EmailMessage("Hello","Your Leads","myemail@gmail.com",["myemail@gmail.com"])
    message.attach('invoice.csv', data(), 'text/csv')
    #message.to="myemail@gmail.com"
    message.send()
    return HttpResponseRedirect('/')
```

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Is there a particular reason you're using an additional function at all?  Just build your csv in memory - you can't avoid that if you're attaching it to email - and send that.

```
assigned_leads = lead.objects.filter(assigned_to__in=usercompany).distinct()
csvfile = StringIO.StringIO()
csvwriter = csv.writer(csvfile)
for leads in assigned_leads:
    csvwriter.writerow([leads.business_name, leads.first_name, leads.last_name, leads.email, leads.phone_number,leads.address, leads.city, leads.state, leads.zipcode, leads.submission_date, leads.time_frame, leads.comments])
message = EmailMessage("Hello","Your Leads","myemail@gmail.com",["myemail@gmail.com"])
message.attach('invoice.csv', csvfile.getvalue(), 'text/csv')
```

Comment: Great answer, just the order of message.attach is wrong. It should be: message.attach('invoice.csv',  'text/csv', csvfile.getvalue())

Comment: @user3167654 - are you sure? The docs say: "Alternatively, you can pass attach() three arguments: filename, content and mimetype. filename is the name of the file attachment as it will appear in the email, content is the data that will be contained inside the attachment and mimetype is the optional MIME type for the attachment." And the example given in the docs uses that same order, with minie type last. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/email/#emailmessage-objects

Comment: Yes you are correct sorry. I was looking at Flask mail's order

Comment: I am also using the same code but I am getting the below error. FYI I am using io.StringIO() as I am using python 3.6.

TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'

Comment: @AnkitSingh - I haven't personally used Django w/Python 3, but from that exception it looks like it's telling you what's going on - it expects (encoded) bytes rather than an encoding-agnostic Unicode string. `csv.writer()` expects a text mode filelike object, so `StringIO` is correct there - you'll need to encode before attaching. I think `csvfile.getvalue().encode(...)` should be sufficient - probably with utf-8 as your encoding choice but it could possibly be something different.

Comment: @PeterDeGlopper Thanks!! Just figured it out yesterday that the problem was with the package that I was using for sending emails. I tried encoding it but the issue was with the package itself. Had to go on, edit the package and encode there. Thanks though!

Comment: Why you use csvfile = StringIO.StringIO() instead of open the file and write it?

Comment: @Gimbo - that builds the result in memory rather than (as a file would) on disk. No need to deal with disk i/o latency if you don't have to.

Answer (score 8):

Python 3 and `DictWriter` example:

```
import csv
from io import StringIO
from django.core.mail import EmailMessage

rows = [{'col1': 'value1', 'col2': 'value2'}]
csvfile = StringIO()
fieldnames = list(rows[0].keys())

writer = csv.DictWriter(csvfile, fieldnames=fieldnames)
writer.writeheader()
writer.writerows(rows)

email = EmailMessage(
        'Subject',
        'Body',
        'from@email.com',
        ['to@email.com'],
    )
email.attach('file.csv', csvfile.getvalue(), 'text/csv')
email.send()
```

Answer (score -2):

```
Neither are working :(

Approach 1:
        msg = EmailMultiAlternatives(subject, body, from_email, [to])
        msg.attach_alternative(file_content, "text/html")
        msg.content_subtype = 'html'
        msg.send()

Approach 2: 
        # email = EmailMessage(
        #     'Report Subject',
        #     "body",
        #     'xx@yy.com',
        #     ['zz@uu.com'],
        #     connection=connection,
        # )
        # email.attach('Report.html', body, 'text/html')
        # email.send()
```

Comment: Please comment/explain your solution.